Snowpipe/Snowflake Loading JSON
If we have the following JSON:
{  
   "root":[  
      {
         "id":1,  
         "kind":"person",
         "fullName":"John Doe",
         "age":22,
         "gender":"Male"
      },
      {
         "id":2,  
         "kind":"person",
         "fullName":"Mike Jones",
         "age":35,
         "gender":"Male"
      },
      {
         "id":3,  
         "kind":"person",
         "fullName":"Jane Doe",
         "age":22,
         "gender":"Female"
      }
   ]
}

How can we load the rows using this format to a Snowflake Table. Is it possible to use Snowpipe with the root key? What might the query look like?
Or does the format need to be the below where it is removed (the below works, but above is what we're working with unless we of course pre-process it, but we're hoping Snowpipe has the ability to do so)?
[  
    {  
       "id":1,
       "kind":"person",
       "fullName":"John Doe",
       "age":22,
       "gender":"Male"
    },
    {
       "id":2,  
       "kind":"person",
       "fullName":"Mike Jones",
       "age":35,
       "gender":"Male"
    },
    {
       "id":3,  
       "kind":"person",
       "fullName":"Jane Doe",
       "age":22,
       "gender":"Female"
    }
]

Any examples of ingesting it, like the first example where each row is loaded into a table (data is stored in S3 bucket)
Using snowflake queries seems possible. But I haven't found a way in Snowpipe.
Snowflake Parsing

Have you tried using STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = TRUE?

That works with the second example assuming preprocess it. But the first example which I'm hoping to fix it doesn't have an outer array (object and inner array)
